# Errorcode 7503 - Application is not registered in our store

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I try to receive Call information's via the Graph API. To be accurate - I try to run Example 5 from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but I only receive the following Error:

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"7503\",\"message\":\"Application is not registered in our store.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-08-20T14:34:37",
            "request-id": "1ea2bdf0-76fd-4f76-b609-61fb22cfc92b",
            "client-request-id": "1ea2bdf0-76fd-4f76-b609-61fb22cfc92b"
        }
    }
}
```

My Request looks like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
  "callbackUri": "https://bot.contoso.com/callback",
  "requestedModalities": [
    "audio"
  ],
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
    "preFetchMedia": [
     {
       "uri": "https://cdn.contoso.com/beep.wav",
       "resourceId": "f8971b04-b53e-418c-9222-c82ce681a582"
     },
     {
       "uri": "https://cdn.contoso.com/cool.wav",
       "resourceId": "86dc814b-c172-4428-9112-60f8ecae1edb"
     }
    ]
  },
  "chatInfo": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.chatInfo",
    "threadId": "19:meeting_ZThiYjNjZjYtZGZlZC00ZTMwLTkwZTAtNTllOTQ0ZjU3YmM0@thread.v2",
    "messageId": "0"
  },
  "meetingInfo": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.organizerMeetingInfo",
    "organizer": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
      "user": {
            "id": "a6acfa8d-668b-496b-8eb9-f23509fe452d",
            "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identity",
            "displayName": "ME",
            "tenantId": "36bf0149-5b2b-4158-896d-e409b491f89b"
        }
    },
    "allowConversationWithoutHost": true
  },
  "tenantId":"36bf0149-5b2b-4158-896d-e409b491f89b"
}
```

I use Postman to call the API. I use an Application Token with my AppID, AppSecret and my dev tenant (no user credentials).  My Token has the needed rols:

```
  "roles": [
    "Calls.JoinGroupCall.All",
    "Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All",
    "Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Calls.AccessMedia.All",
    "Calls.Initiate.All"
  ],
```

Because I receive a Token - it makes no sense for me the receive the Error Msg "Application is not registered in our store." Is there more than an app registration needed to call this route?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you register the app as a bot? See the docs for that on [Register calls and meetings bot for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot). This API can only be called from an app registered as a bot.

Comment: @danstan possible to add the permissions to existing Microsoft app used for Microsoft 365 data using graph APIs?

Comment: @vinitpayal I suggest you open a new question with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Registering as a bot was the solution.

Comment: I registered it as a bot with the same APP ID used for application registration still I am getting the same error message. To be more precise opted for the Pre registered APP ID instead of new MS APP ID.

Comment: what if we are calling it from an API (a non-bot solution)? where should we register?